# Method not returning wanted variables Javascript

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm currently working on creating a discord bot in javascript using `discord.js` and I'm attempting to create a `!warn command`.
I have an issue with returning the variables that I've read from the `.txt file` that contains the variables.

It outputs the proper variables to the console but for testing purposes I'm replying to the message with the variables they show up as undefined.

This is what I'm getting in discord:

> Marrca35: !warn @Marrca35 test
>
> BOT
>
> Blamemar: @Marrca35, undefined undefined
>
> BOT
>
> Blamemar: @Marrca35, Marrca35 Has been warned!
>
> This is what I'm getting in the console:
>
> 311828506046627841:0
>
> [ '311828506046627841', '0' ]

The contents of my `txt file` are:

```
311828506046627841:0

283065950394122240:0
```

This is the warn command:

```
           // Command for warning listed player.
            // Syntax -> !warn playername (o)reason
        case "!warn": {
            if (msg.member.roles.cache.some(r => ["Admin", "Moderator"].includes(r.name))) {
                try {
                    var target = msg.mentions.members.first()
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log('No player mentioned!')
                    msg.reply("Player mentioned does not exist!")
                    return
                }
                var warn = () => {
                    var mesg = rdWrC()
                    msg.reply(mesg)
                    target.createDM()
                    target.send("You have been warned!").then(msg => console.log(`Sent message: ${msg.content}`)).catch(console.error);
                    target.send("Reason: " + command[2]).then(msg => console.log(`Sent message: ${msg.content}`)).catch(console.error);
                    msg.reply(target.displayName + " Has been warned!")
                    msg.guild.channels.resolve("714362259601621043").send(target.displayName + " count: " + "");
                    console.log(mesg)
                }
                warn()
            }
            break;
        }
```

```
function rdWrC() {
    var id, id2, id3
    fs.readFile('warn_count.txt', (error, txtString) => {
        if (error) throw err;
        var _rTA = txtString.toString().split(":")
        //console.log(_rTA)
        id = _rTA[0]
        id2 = _rTA[1]
        id3 = _rTA[2]
        //console.log(id)
        //console.log(count)
        var _rT = id2 + " " + id3
        console.log(_rT)
        return _rT
    })
}
```

Comment: Try using fs.readFileSync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use fs.readFileSync to read from your file, otherwise it will return the variable before the reading is finsihed.

Another way would be to put the return statement inside the callback function:

```
function rdWrC() {
    var id, count
    fs.readFile('warn_count.txt', (error, txtString) => {
        if (error) throw err;
        console.log(txtString.toString());
        var _rTA = txtString.toString().split(":")
        console.log(_rTA)
        id = _rTA[0]
        count = _rTA[1]
        var _rT = id + " " + count
        return _rT
    })
}
```